# How to select following siblings until a certain sibling

Tags: xpath, xquery

I'm currently working with VDA message types that have been convert to xml using a custom xml converter.  However each header and line record in the source document is at the same level, as in the sample below:

```
<root>
    <row>
        <Record_type>512</Record_type>
        <Customer_item_Number>A0528406</Customer_item_Number>
        <Supplier_item_number>10962915</Supplier_item_number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Record_type>513</Record_type>
        <Date>170306</Date>
        <Quantity>115</Quantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Record_type>513</Record_type>
        <Date>190306</Date>
        <Quantity>97</Quantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Record_type>512</Record_type>
        <Customer_item_Number>A0528433</Customer_item_Number>
        <Supplier_item_number>10962916</Supplier_item_number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Record_type>513</Record_type>
        <Date>170306</Date>
        <Quantity>115</Quantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Record_type>513</Record_type>
        <Date>170306</Date>
        <Quantity>115</Quantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Record_type>513</Record_type>
        <Date>170306</Date>
        <Quantity>115</Quantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Record_type>513</Record_type>
        <Date>170306</Date>
        <Quantity>115</Quantity>
    </row>
</root>
```

(512) record types are headers, the following (513) record types are lines for the preceding (512) record above it.

I am struggling to format this message, so that the lines (513) are indented underneath each header (512) record.

i.e. required output, something like this.

```
<root>
    <Header>
        <Record_type>512</Record_type>
        <Customer_item_Number>A0528406</Customer_item_Number>
        <Supplier_item_number>10962915</Supplier_item_number>
        <Line>
            <Record_type>513</Record_type>
            <Date>170306</Date>
            <Quantity>115</Quantity>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Record_type>513</Record_type>
            <Date>190306</Date>
            <Quantity>97</Quantity>
        </Line>
    </Header>
    <Header>
        <Record_type>512</Record_type>
        <Customer_item_Number>A0528433</Customer_item_Number>
        <Supplier_item_number>10962916</Supplier_item_number>
        <Line>
            <Record_type>513</Record_type>
            <Date>170306</Date>
            <Quantity>115</Quantity>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Record_type>513</Record_type>
            <Date>170306</Date>
            <Quantity>115</Quantity>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Record_type>513</Record_type>
            <Date>170306</Date>
            <Quantity>115</Quantity>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Record_type>513</Record_type>
            <Date>170306</Date>
            <Quantity>115</Quantity>
        </Line>
    </Header>
</root>
```

I have had some success using following sibling, but I'm unable to link this with preceding-sibling, to filter out only the required records before the next loop.

I am hoping someone will be able to assist. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every `row` that has a `Record_type` of `512`, create a `Header` element.

In order to find the `row` elements for the relevant group of `Line` elements, you want to select the `row` elements that are `following-sibling` from the 512 who's `Record_type = 513` and who's first `preceding-sibling` is the current header.

```
for $header in $doc/root/row[Record_type = 512]
let $lines := $header/following-sibling::row[Record_type = 513]
                [preceding-sibling::row[Record_type = 512][1] = $header] 
return 
  <Header>{ 
    $header/*,
    for $line in $lines
    return <Line>{ $line/* }</Line>
  }</Header>
```

Comment: The results of `preceding-sibling::row[Record_type = 512]` are in document order, so you would need to compare `$header` to the last one, right? The comparison should also be on document identity (using `is`) instead of atomized text contents (forced by `=`).

Comment: I was close, thank you.  I now have my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

In XQuery 3.1 you can use a tumbling window https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-tumbling-windows:

```
<root>
{    
for tumbling window $record in root/row
start $s when $s/Record_type = 512
return
    <Header>
        {
            head($record)/*,
            tail($record) !
                <Line>
                    { * }
                </Line>
        }
    </Header>
}
</root>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMef

Answer (score 1):

If your XQuery processor supports *XQuery 3.0*'s [`window` clauses](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-windows), your query is (at least conceptually) very straight forward and efficient:

```
<root>{
  for tumbling window $w in /root/row
      start when true()
      end next $n when $n/Record_type = '512'
  return <Header>{
    head($w)/*,
    for $line in tail($w)
    return <Line>{$line/*}</Line>
  }</Header>
}</root>
```

Otherwise you have to use the `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` XPath axes as Mads Hansen also shows in his answer:

```
<root>{
  for $header in /root/row[Record_type = '512']
  return <Header>{
    $header/*,
    for $line in $header/following-sibling::row[Record_type = '513']
    let $prev-headers := $line/preceding-sibling::row[Record_type = '512']
    where $prev-headers[last()] is $header
    return <Line>{$line/*}</Line>
  }</Header>
}</root>
```

Here we get all lines after the current header first, and then check for each line if the last header before it is the current one. It is important here to use `is` instead of `=` or `eq` because the latter two work on *atomic items* only. This means that XML nodes are *atomized* (i.e., stripped down to just their concatenated text contents) before the comparison is performed. The `is` operator compares *node identity* instead.

Comment: This is exactly my requirements.  In my mapping tool I did successfully retrieve the results using tumbling.  However, in our live environment it was unsupported.  Thank you.